# Creating mulitple dataframes from Dictionary full of list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key

```
df = {'(5, 1.01, 0.98)': [(Timestamp('2017-08-24 22:35:00'), 
    -201.99999999999915, 19798.0), (Timestamp('2017-08-25 12:10:00'),
    -199.95980000000057, 19598.0402), (Timestamp('2017-08-26 01:35:00'),
    90.00690944516465, 19688.047109445164)], '(6, 1.04, 0.99)': [(Timestamp('2017-
    08-25 16:35:00'), -808.0000000000001, 19192.0), (Timestamp('2017-08-26 
    01:35:00'), 73.45175794973963, 19265.45175794974), (Timestamp('2017-08-26 
    03:55:00'), 85.84402466986793, 19351.295782619607), (Timestamp('2017-08-26 
    11:10:00')]}
```

I have two keys, and multiples values that are a list of tuple for each values. 
How do I create a dataframe containing 3 columns relative to the tuples containing 3 element? 
Is it possibile? 
And Can I create a different dataframe for every key?

Kind Regards

Comment: Didn't know how to post code on multiple rows. Sorry hard to read, but if you copy and paste should be readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hoping for the following

```
             0                    1           2             3
0  (5, 1.01, 0.98)  2017-08-24 22:35:00 -202.000000  19798.000000
1  (5, 1.01, 0.98)  2017-08-25 12:10:00 -199.959800  19598.040200
2  (5, 1.01, 0.98)  2017-08-26 01:35:00   90.006909  19688.047109
```

as an output for

```
{'(5, 1.01, 0.98)': [(Timestamp('2017-08-24 22:35:00'), 
-201.99999999999915, 19798.0), (Timestamp('2017-08-25 12:10:00'),
-199.95980000000057, 19598.0402), (Timestamp('2017-08-26 01:35:00'),
90.00690944516465, 19688.047109445164)]}
```

then you can use

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[k] + list(t) for k, v in df.items() for t in v])
new_df.columns = [to, whatever, you, want]
```

however, if you want to split out the tuple key (first column) then you can modify the above to do that.